# Hide the Enthousiast(woot) badge from the "Recent Badges" roll

Tags: feature-request, activity-badges

There is a continuous stream of "Woot" badges in the "Recent Badges" roll.

**I know it is by design** (it's easy to loose it and to regain it) but it's quite pointless in my opinion.

Comment: Dupe:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8778/maybe-not-show-enthusiast-badge-on-the-sidebar

Comment: @random : +1. Damn... I searched for duplicate just before posting without success... and the auto-suggestion didn't show up anything interesting.

Comment: Some people spend too much time on meta to not have to search to find a dupe. Plus spelling "Enthusiast" correctly would have helped.

Comment: `spelling "Enthusiast" correctly` ... *sic*...

Comment: It's not "easy to lose it and regain it". It's a one-time deal: you show up for thirty days and you get the badge. End of story.

Comment: @random: nope.. it's just that usually it's me who's a grammar fascist :)

Comment: @mmyers: If one day you don't show up, you will loose it, no ?

Comment: No, you will never lose it (and you'd certainly better not loose it, or people will get hurt).

Comment: I have the badge on SF even though I hardly ever visit anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [because some people might not get it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13049/let-people-still-earn-the-woot-badge-if-they-register-for-a-holiday) doesn't mean the sponsor of the badge shouldn't have the badges flowing down the site every now and then.

Comment: Yeah... I saw your answer, and I added mine :-p. But you have a point. Maybe hide it after the sponsoring period is over ?

Comment: Or maybe just rename it to your suggestion as a sort of "badge of people who need to get out more"